# Mongoose on node, collection.find() always executes last no matter where i put the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to all of this web development programming. I'm currently learning for 1 or 2 months now. and trying to create a local database system using node and mongodb. I'm having trouble understanding the sequence of mongoose collection.find(). I want to run the `collection.find()` to get some data then pass it to another function but it seems the `collection.find()` always executes last no matter where i put the code.

My code is something like this:

```
function getInitial() {
  ticket.find(function (err, tickets) {
  totalTickets = tickets.length;
  console.log("Done verifying tickets");
});
    
gentInitial();
    
function lastFunction() {
  console.log("this should be the last to execute");
}

lastFunction();
```

The output of this code is:

> "this should be the last to execute"
>
> "Done verifying tickets"

Desired output is:

> "Done verifying tickets"
> "this should be the last to execute"

Comment: You should spend some time grasping the asynchronous nature of Javascrip programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find runs async, so the callback in getInitial() gets executed after everything else in the OP code. Fixing the code to account for the fact that the find runs asynchronously...

```
async function getInitial() {
  let tickets = await ticket.find();
  totalTickets = tickets.length;
  console.log("Done verifying tickets");
}

function lastFunction() {
  console.log("this should be the last to execute");
}

async function test() {
  await gentInitial();
  lastFunction();
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

like you have discovered, callbacks are not synchronous. (ticket.find takes time to return data)

if you want to execute something after find has returned data then execute it from inside the callback.

```
    function getInitial() {
       ticket.find(function (err, tickets) {
           totalTickets = tickets.length;
           console.log("Done verifying tickets");

           // execute the rest of the code here
           lastFunction();
       });
    }

    function lastFunction() {
        console.log("this should be the last to execute");
    }

    getInitial();
```

Please note that this way of coding from callbacks to callbacks leads the the callback hell : http://callbackhell.com/

the only way to have clean code and avoid thinking in callbacks too much is my using promises and using the await syntax.

example :

```
// now it works sequentially without callbacks
const data = await Character.find();
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually straight forward. You're using callback which run syncronously. While lastfunction() directly calls **console.log()**.

Mongoose call goes through a few step before it can actually return the result of the query you run and because nodeJS is a single threaded language, it'll move on to the next code (lastfunction in your case) while keeping the syncronous call in memory. Then gives you the result once the data have been fetched.

You can use asyn...await to make Mongoose give you the result before moving on to the next code.

Your code should be like this:

```
const getInitial = async() => {
 try{
  const tickets = await ticket.find({});
  const totalTickets = tickets.length;
  console.log("Done verifying tickets");
 } catch(e){
  console.log(e)
 }
}

getInitial();

function lastFunction() {
    console.log("this should be the last to execute");
    }

lastFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an **asynchronous** function because it will take time to **query database** and report it back to you.
Also try leaning about **event loop** in node.js.
There is plenty sources online.
Img for reference:-
[image]